# YouTube API and the video tag

Tags: api, html, video, youtube

Is there a way to use something like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YJp7tqRyJAI" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.youtube.com/v/YJp7tqRyJAI" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I've looked into the api and all I've found is that i can use an iframe which embeds a flash version... But on Google I've found people wondering how to build a custom ui or an autoplay feature with the html5-youtube-api...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.filsh.net/ did the job!